# Library for applying a Nonuniform DFT over simple time series data from sensors

Tags: python, c++, analytics, real-time, signal-processing

I have real-time data from sensors monitoring pumps. I need to analyze the duty-cycle of the pumps in the frequency domain. I am pretty rusty in FFT, so I was hoping to find a C++ or Python library that would have a simple API taking in time-series data (i.e. a series of {timestamp, value} real-number pairs), and returning a series of frequencies, amplitudes and phases.

I found several packages taking in complex number series. Moreover, their example code typically uses random data as input, which makes it hard to integrate with production code. A Matlab-based solution would also be hard for me to integrate into my code.

One of the packages I've found:

https://github.com/flatironinstitute/finufft

I know that the problem is my lack of knowledge, but given that sensor-data analysis is such a hot topic today, I was surprised to realize that such a library is so hard to find.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Always look first at numpy or scipy libraries. Perhaps https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/routines.fft.html

Answer (score 0):

With Python technical computing, the first place you should look for functions is the [Numpy](https://numpy.org/) and [Scipy](https://www.scipy.org/) libraries. It is these libraries that allow you to replace MATLAB with Python in many instances. There are are a set of Numpy functions for [discrete fourier transforms](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/routines.fft.html). Also for [Scipy there are fft functions](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/fftpack.html). If the data is not sampled a regular intervals, you might want to [resample it](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.resample.html).